# How to store a date from server in UTC format in realm DB (date from server is also in UTC)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

The date from server is `2017-12-04T16:30:00+00:00`
the date which i converted using format `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` is `04/12/2017 04:40:00 PM`.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the ISO8601 date as it is?

Comment: The iso8601 format converts the date to local timezone.

Comment: The iso8601 format does not convert anything. It's just a string.

Comment: I think more info is needed before the question can be accurately answered. The is8601 is a string of characters and doesn't do any conversion. However, you may be using a function or object that does - can you include your date handling code in your question? i.e. how are you getting the date from the server, how is it being stored in code and how are you writing it to Realm... and what kind of Realm object are you using? Date? String? something else?

Comment: I resolved the issue.

The date i receive from server is in UTC format. And was storing the date in local format, which caused issue.

Solution:
I first convert server time to local timezone and then converted to UTC format and stored in Realm. It worked for me.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: Glad you found the solution! In the future it's best practice to include code in your question and then if you come up with an answer, you can select to add your own answer with the updated code. That's the best way to help the stackoverflow community so they can follow the code instead of just a description. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a bit more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. I use it as an extension. You can just modify the format as you want it.

```
extension Formatter {
static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    return formatter
}()}
```

Comment: A formatter which is hardcoded with `'Z'` cannot handle string to date conversions if the ISO string you're converting doesn't happen to use the `Z` format. It's safer to use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"` or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"` or use `ISO8601DateFormatter` with the milliseconds option. This is especially true as the input string bears `+00:00`, not `Z` in it.